# SECTION and numbers next to it

Tags: sectioning

I have a problem about sections. In my country we use references to the sources next to the section name. Could you please help me how to make this possible in Latex? I can not figure it out.
Also this numbers can not be shown in the table of contents.

Thank you very much for any help !

[image]

Comment: Use use the optional part of the sectioning command to provide the text which goes to the ToC. For example: `\section[STRIHANI]{STRIHANI\cite{knuth2019}}`. It is the same as if you need a footnote in the section command.

Answer (score 1):

To add a citation to the heading title, you use the optional, square bracket to add the text that shall go into the table of contents. Normally, you copy the full heading text without the citations into the square brackets that form the optional argument to the sectioning command.

```
\section[Words words words]{Words words words~\cite{2}, \cite{2}}
```

You can use the same strategy if you need a footnote in the heading. If the heading is long, you may also abbreviate it so that the text in the ToC is shorter. The text in the bracket is also the text that goes into the running header, if case you document has one. (The document file below is a slightly modified example file from [biblatex](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatexbib.bib}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[Standard citation commands]{Standard citation commands\parencite{arnholm1973} \cite{gorton}}

\subsection{The \cmd{cite} command}

\cite{arnholm1973}

\cite[59]{arnholm1973}

\cite[see][]{arnholm1973}

\cite[see][59--63]{arnholm1973}

\cite{gorton}

\cite[59]{gorton}

\cite[see][]{gorton}

\cite[see][59--63]{gorton}


\subsection{The \cmd{parencite} command}

This is just filler text \parencite{arnholm1973}.

This is just filler text \parencite[59]{arnholm1973}.

This is just filler text \parencite[see][]{arnholm1973}.

This is just filler text \parencite[see][59--63]{arnholm1973}.

\subsection{The \cmd{footcite} command}


This is just filler text.\footcite{arnholm1973}

This is just filler text.\footcite[59]{arnholm1973}

This is just filler text.\footcite[See][]{arnholm1973}

This is just filler text.\footcite[See][59--63]{arnholm1973}

\subsection*{The \cmd{textcite} command}


\textcite{arnholm1973} show that this is just filler text.

\textcite[59]{arnholm1973} show that this is just filler text.

\textcite[see][]{arnholm1973} show that this is just filler text.

\textcite[see][59--63]{arnholm1973} show that this is just filler text.

\section{Style-independent commands}

\subsection{The \cmd{autocite} command}

This is just filler text \autocite{arnholm1973}.

\section{Text commands}

\citeauthor{arnholm1973} show that this is just filler text.

See the \citetitle{arnholm1973} for more filler text.

See also: \citetitle*{arnholm1973}. It has more filler text.

\citetitle*{arnholm1973} by \citeauthor{arnholm1973} was
published in \citeyear{arnholm1973}.

\section{Special commands}

No citation here.\nocite{knuth:ct}

\fullcite{arnholm1973}

This is just filler text.\footfullcite{arnholm1973}

\section{Low-level commands}

\citename{arnholm1973}{author}

\citelist{arnholm1973}{publisher}

\citefield{arnholm1973}{title}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

*bibfile*

```
@BOOK{arnholm1973,
  author = {Arnholm, Carl Jacob},
  title = {Almindelig obligasjonsrett},
  year = {1973},
  keywords = {obligasjonsrett},
  edition = {2},
  isbn = {8251802164},
  language = {norsk},
  location = {Oslo},
  publisher = {Tanum-Norli},
  timestamp = {2019.10.20}
}

@BOOK{dahlman2005,
  author = {Dahlman, Christian},
  title = {Studier i rättsekonomi : festskrift till Ingemar Ståhl},
  year = {2005},
  keywords = {Rättsekonomi ; Law And Economics ; Festskrift ; Samhällsvetenskap ; Juridik ; Social Sciences ; Law},
  isbn = {9789144037868},
  language = {swe}
}


@INBOOK{gorton,
  author = {Gorton, Lars and Samuelsson, Per},
  title = {Kontraktuella viten},
  crossref = {dahlman2005},
  language = {swedish},
  timestamp = {2019.10.20}
}
```